# Removing excess parameter pack parameters with minimal overhead

Tags: c++

I want to make a function object that allows me to bind a function that has less parameters than the function object.

So for example:

```
int SomeFunction(int i) { return i * i; }

Function<int, int, float> function(&SomeFunction);
```

Calling `function(5, 3.14f);` would call the function with `5` as the parameter, and `3.14f` would simply be ignored.

The goal is to create something similar to Qt's signal and slot mechanism in standard C++.

What kind of template magic can I use to achieve this?

Comment: I would have a good think about your design and coding

Comment: @EdHeal If you don't want to help, that's fine. If you have constructive criticism, that's also fine. But please don't go around telling people that their code is bad without explanation.

Comment: Just seems to me that you are trying to solve a problem  that should not exist in the first place with a better design and/or coding

Comment: This looks very much like [an XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where you ask why your attempted solution Y doesn't work, instead of asking how to solve X.

Comment: @EdHeal Added the context to the main post. TL;DR; signal/slot system similar to Qt. If you could explain what is wrong with it and a better solution (possibly in an awnser) then that would be great.

Comment: @Hedanito : FYI, I just found your question because I was searching for removing excess parameter pack parameters in order to build a signal/slots system of my own.  I think its an extremely logical question given the specific application.  More generally, I think its important to be able to dynamically manipulate types for this and other goals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `std::tuple` and `std::function`:

```
template<typename Ret, typename... Ts>
class Function{
public:
    template<typename...Us>
    Function(Ret(*f)(Us...)) : Function(std::index_sequence_for<Us...>{}, f) {}


    template <typename ... Us>
    Ret call(Us&&... args)
    {
        return mF(std::forward<Us>(args)...);
    }

private:
    template<std::size_t... Is, typename...Us>
    Function(std::index_sequence<Is...>, Ret(*f)(Us...))
    {
        mF = [f](Ts... args)
        {
            return f(std::get<Is>(std::forward_as_tuple(args...))...);
        };
    }

private:
    std::function<Ret(Ts...)> mF;
};
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/EGVpID)